# "will + past participle" is it correct?

Tags: grammar

I have seen these structures being used several times in York, UK (by native speakers).

- a. "He will lived at address Y."
- b. "He be staying at address Y."

I am wondering if it is:

1. grammatically correct?
2. poor English, but colloquial.
3. totally wrong and strange, representing speakers lack of English literacy.

Thanks you guys

Comment: Are you quite sure this is a native speaker? You are absolutely right that neither of those two constructions is acceptable in English. The intended phrasing was perhaps “will be staying”.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: _Will_, like all modal auxiliary verbs, must be followed by the infinitive verb form, not the past participle.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, yep, later on I saw her. Couldn't be more British!

Comment: @FumbleFingers is this Q&A site only for English native speakers?! If you had read my Q, it was about IF this structure is grammatically valid, or if it is a slang or something. I also suspected it might bear a typo (although very strange, coming from a native speaker, and being repeated twice), but I needed confirmation form you guys. How could I have simply assumed it was a typo and refrained myself from asking? 

I read the help section of this site, and I believe my question, asking if structure A is ungrammatical or not, fits within the site guideline.

Comment: @ cybergeek654: ELU certainly isn't "only for native speakers" (at least a couple of our mods aren't). But nor is it a suitable site for asking *really* basic questions like yours (you should consider [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)). By the way, the answers you've been given are pretty misleading anyway - your #1 is ***completely invalid*** in every dialect I've ever come across, but there are [still] quite a few dialectal contexts where #2 is perfectly acceptable (though it's definitely ungrammatical in all "mainstream" versions of English).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American English, both are wrong. It should be "had lived" or "will be living" (or "will live"), depending on context and timing.

Comment: Thanks.

Then what is the difference between: "will live" and "will be living"?

Comment: "Will be living" is passive voice. "Will live" is active voice.

Comment: *Will be living* is not passive but active: future progressive/continuous. Future passive would be *will be lived*: "Mr. X' life will be lived at Y/in misery/on $80,000 per year."

Comment: @DrRandy, Is there any difference in meaning? Say between these two sentences:
I will be living there from January till March.
I will live there from January till March.

Comment: "Will be" is future progressive, and is expected to be continuous. "Will" is future simple, which is usually used to express a fact, a conditional, or a single (or repetitive) action. In this case, with a defined endpoint, either is acceptable. If you were moving in January for an indefinite period, "I will be living there starting in January" would be preferred.

Comment: And British English.

Comment: "live" is intransitive so it can't have a passive form!

Answer (score 2):

Without further context it is impossible to say this for certain, but it looks like a typing error for "will have lived".